# Constructor object used as method type

Tags: java

I have a class with the following Constructor

```
public Customer()
 {
      lastName = "???";
      firstName = "???";
      customerID = 0;
      matineeTickets = 0;
      normalTickets = 0;
      totalCost = 0.0;
  }
```

In a separate class I need to use the object Customer to return the value stored in a 2d array. When I attempt to return the value I get "incompatible types, String cannot be converted to Customer" I am not sure how to return type Customer.

```
    private Customer getCustomerAt(int row, int col){

    Customer cust = new Customer();


        for(int r = 0; r < row; r++){

            for(int c = 0; c < col; c++){

               cust = seating[r][c];

            }

        }


    return cust;
}
```

seating is an array defined previously in the same class.

Thanks

Comment: Is `seating` an array of `String[]` or of `Customer[]`?

Comment: Firstly: `Customer cust = new Customer(temp);`

You are creating a new `Customer` object by sending `temp` as a method parameter.

But look at your constructor. It takes zero arguments:

    `public Customer()`

Comment: It is an array of String []

Comment: Also, the logic of your method makes no sense.  You are doing simple assignment inside a for-loop, which is just going to throw the previous value away each time.  Your entire method is equivalent to `return seating[row-1][col-1];`

Comment: @FMP Well, there you go.  Your variable is of type `Customer`, so you cannot assign a `String` object to it.

Comment: Looks to be more than just a little bit of confusion about error messages.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I will fix the loop,  I butchered trying to figure out my original problem. Since my variable is type Customer, how can I go about returning the string located in the array? Should I not create a new Customer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that the array seating is of type customer i.e. it should hold objects of type customer.

Comment: So rather than defining the array as type string,  I should simply define it as type Customer?

Comment: Yes, it is an Array of Customers, not of Strings.